# Writing test for destroy action but getting No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to write an rspec test for my destroy action of my `addresses_controller`. I am running into an issue where it cannot find my route even though I clearly see it in my `rake routes`.

I am getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: delete action, params
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"addresses"}
```

**Here is my test:**

```
describe '#destroy' do
  let (:old_address) { FactoryGirl.create(:address, addressable: user) }

  let(:action) { :destroy }
  let(:params) {   }
  let(:referer) { '/' }


  before do
    request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = referer
    login_user user, request
  end

  it 'redirects back' do
    delete action, params
    expect(response).to redirect_to(referer)
  end

end
```

**rake routes:**

```
DELETE /addresses/:id(.:format)                   addresses#destroy
```

**addresses_controller.rb:**

```
def destroy
  address = Address.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if address.present? && address.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Address deleted."
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

**Why is it not detecting my routes when I can manually trigger it and it appears in my rake routes?**

Comment: Are you sending an ID? I don't see it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not, but I don't think it should matter at this point since it can't even find the routes.

Comment: Rails can't find the route because you are not sending ID. You have to have ID in your params. Otherwise rails won't associate the route correctly. Here is detailed description of routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: 99% of situations, where you have routing problems in testing point to the problems with params.

Comment: @Huy As mentioned by others, if there's no ID, there's no route to match: your route explicitly includes an id.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewton. You were spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You`re missing params. (routes need to have it to figure out url)

try `let(:params) { id: old_address.id}`